# Is Val and get() redundant in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, getter, setter, android-viewbinding

In the android documentation it is suggested that when implementing viewBinding to use the following code:

```
private var _binding: FragmentLetterListBinding? = null

private val binding get() = _binding!!
```

Does the second line have a redundancy since val does not allow the re-SET-ing of a variable and the get() portion ensures that the binding variable is not reassigned.  If not, please explain why.

And why is the line of code above preferred over the following:

```
private val binding = _binding!!
```

Thank you.

Comment: `_binding` can be changed. Here using a getter, which does the force unwrap, is to provide you a handy shortcut in the rest of the code so that you don't have to unwrap the optional every time. This trick assumes you know exactly when would `_binding` become `null` and the logic of your code never access it when it is null.

Comment: This question’s answers explain why the example does it this way. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68850576/506796